# Which sound quality is easier on iPhone processor?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a piano-like app for iPhone, and currently recording every mp3 for a short tone for each key. Which sound quality better fits for that, 64kbps or 128 kbps?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. Some people won't hear the difference, but if you're using headphones a lot of people will hear it, so use the higher quality (IMHO even 128kbps is way too low for MP3... I'd go for 192kbps).

As for CPU load: decoding and playing MP3 is so cheap on the iPhone that you won't notice any difference, the CPU load of a high-quality MP3 is "very low" instead of "ridiculously low". Don't worry about it (just for comparison, I'm doing realtime MPEG-2 video and audio decoding in software, even the iPhone 3GS can cope with that).

Answer (score 0):

The lower the bitrate, the less processing required, and the lower the quality.  Since your app is all about the music, it makes sence to have better quality.  If the sound was just for background or effect, it might be acceptable to reduce the quality.